# How to prove that hypotenuse of differential triangle coincides with the segment of the curve?

Tags: infinitesimals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read in one article that "for any curve given by an algebraic equation, the hypotenuse of the differential triangle generated by an infinitesimal abscissal increment $\varepsilon$ coincides with the segment of the curve between $x$ and $x+\varepsilon$".

How to prove that hypotenuse of differential triangle coincide with the segment of the curve?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one works in synthetic differential geometry, as the tag indicates, there is not much to prove here.

The Kock-Lawvere axiom literally says that all curves are linear on the infinitesimal scale. So the segment of the curve between $x$ and $x+\varepsilon$ is a line segment. The hypotenuse of the triangle between $x$ and $x+\varepsilon$ is also a line segment. Since these two line segments have the same endpoints, they coincide.

So the hypotenuse of the differential triangle coincides with the segment of the curve.

Of course, Nieuwentijdt's work precedes synthetic differential geometry by centuries, and I don't know whether *his proof* of this fact goes in a way comparable to the one outlined above: that's perhaps best left to some kind of StackExchange site where historians of science and mathematics congregate.

Comment: I've always been interested why earlier undefined object (in this case - infinitesimal $\varepsilon$) is used in Kock-Lawvere axiom. If we don't know precisely that $\varepsilon$ exists and satisfies $\varepsilon^2=0$ then how can we work with it? @Z. A. K.

Comment: *All* axioms proceed from earlier-undefined objects, including the axioms of set theory (which assert properties that all sets satisfy, without further defining the concept of set itself), the axioms of geometry (the concept of point and line), and so on. Yet we can work with sets, lines, etc. just fine. But note that the KL axiom in particular says something about "all nilsquare infinitesimals $\varepsilon$" , and does not commit to or require the existence of any specific such infinitesimal.

Comment: How can we conclude that nilsquare infinitesimal exists if we only know that $x^2=0$? @Z. A. K.

Comment: The definition of nilsquare infinitesimal is "a quantity $x$ that satisfies $x^2=0$". There is at least one such quantity, since $0^2=0$.

Comment: Yes. But we don't know that other infinitesimals exist. Am I right that we use KL axiom to know that such infinitesimals exist? (we have contradiction with {0})

Comment: The KL axiom (combined with all other axioms of SDG) implies that $\neg \forall x. x^2=0 \rightarrow x=0$ (this is presented early on in e.g. Kock's book). It does not imply $\exists x. x^2=0 \wedge x \neq 0$: the latter is just plain false in SDG. These two are not equivalent sinve the logic of SDG is not classical.

Comment: How to explain following similar example?

Let $x^2=9$ and $3x^2-10x+3=0$ for all unique $x$ which satisfy this equation. We prove that only x={3} isn't true because there are 2 unique roots of this equation. Then x={3,-10} but $-10$ doesn't satisfy $x^2=9$. It's double contradiction.

Where did I go wrong? Thanks. @Z. A. K.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand this, in particular why $x$ belongs to ${3,-10}$. Perhaps it's worth posting it as a question, with appropriate detail, so that I or someone else can answer (also, we're hitting comment limits on this answer, and I don't use the chat since the user interface is all kinds of horrible).