How is it possible that graph of function $y=x^2$ doesn't coincide with its infinitesimally small segment of tangent line in Non-standard analysis?
As is known, graph of function $y=x^2$ touches the axis $X$ not only at point $(0,0)$. There is infinitesimally small segment of tangent line (at the point $(0,0)$) that coincides with this graph (it's shown in Synthethic differential geometry or in example with Leibniz infinitesimals). But in Non-standard analysis (hyperreals) graph doesn't touch the axis $X$ on infinitesimally small segment.
How is it possible?
Or where did I go wrong?
Thanks!

Why do you think there is a contradiction? These are two very different frameworks, which even use two different kinds of underlying logic (intuitionistic for smooth infinitesimal analysis, and classical for nonstandard analysis). What nonstandard analysis does prove is that, infinitesimally close to $x=0$, the tangent line is infinitesimally close to the curve (indeed, this is just the statement of continuity in nonstandard analysis).

I agree with the comment of @NicholasTodoroff, but let me add a possibly helpful observation. In synthetic differential geometry, the infinitesimal $x$ values rflevant to your question, the ones where the parabola and the  tangent line coincide, satisfy $x^2=0$. There are no non-zero such $x$ in the non-=standard real line,, because there are none in the standard real line, and the transfer principle says the situation is the same inc the non-standard line.

[continuation of previouis comment:]  In this sense, one could intuitively regard the nilpotent infinitesimals od synthetic differential geometry as being even smaller than the infinitesimals of nonstandard analysis.

When you write that "graph of function $y=x^2$  touches the axis X not only at point (0,0)", you should be aware of the fact that in Synthetic Differential Geometry, one cannot actually prove the existence of a nonzero point on the $x$-axis that would lie on the graph, in spite of the fact that in SDG one can speak of "local straightness" of the graph (here the essential ingredient is the intuitionistic background logic).  As far as Nonstandard Analysis is concerned, one can show that no other point of the $x$-axis will lie on the graph (here the background logic is classical).  As far as your reference to "Leibniz infinitesimals", it is not clear which formalisation you have in mind here.

When I wrote about SDG and Leibniz infinitesimals I mean that Leibniz infinitesimals can be regarded as a precursor to SDG. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gottfried+Leibniz) It follows from this that $x=0$ isn't only solution for $x^2=0$ and graph of function $y=x^2$ touches the axis $X$ not only at one point. I read about it in this source: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/#ContInfiSeveEighCent. (also see my question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788973/how-to-prove-that-hypotenuse-of-differential-triangle-coincides-with-the-segment) @Mikhail Katz

In Leibniz all infinitesimals are invertible.

I mean another thing. Key thing is that graph of function lay upon axis X as we know by Leibniz infinitesimals. Then we use this fact to conclude that $dx^2$ is equal to $0$ @Mikhail Katz

In Leibniz, an infinitesimal is either zero or nonzero, and if it is nonzero then $dx^2$ is also nonzero.

Sorry, it's my mistake, I wrote $dx^2$ instead of $\varepsilon^2$ @Mikhail Katz

No difference, $\varepsilon^2$ will also be nonzero in Leibniz.

Leibniz infinitesimal only help us to know that graph of function lay upon axis X. We have point $(\varepsilon, 0)$ on the graph. Then by definition of function $\varepsilon^2=0$ . @Mikhail Katz

There are no such phenomena in Leibniz.

It's not phenomena. :) In Leibniz - point $(dx, dx^2)$ lay upon axis X. But this point and point $(dx, 0)$ are the same points. If we go to another framework we can use this fact. In the different frameworks we can obtain different results for $x^2=0$.

In the ring we obtain that $x>0$ for $x^2=0$. For smooth line (in SDG) we obtain that $x$ is indistinguishable from $0$.

Do you agree that graph of function touches axis X not only one point? @Mikhail Katz

No, I disagree.  Such phenomena don't occur in classical logic, and Leibniz specifically endorses the law of excluded middle in his writing.  MK
